# How can I communicate (send and receive data) back and forth between two servers in two different tabs?

Tags: node.js, server, connection, backend

First of all, this is a project build on Node/Express.

I have two servers (which are two different applications/folders).
**I want to send data from Server 1 (localhost:3000) to Server 2 (localhost:3001).**
In Server 1, I have a form that performs a POST request and sends the input to localhost:3001 (this is just a HTML form with method and action attributes, no further logic behind it), but what happens after submitting the form is that the page reloads and I get redirected to localhost:3001 but on the same tab.

[Server 1 tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3evlm.png)

[Server 2 tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKXXn.png)

[Server 1 tab after submitting the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8u8c.png)

**What I want is the Server 2 tab to reload and display the data on the client once I submit the form from Server 1. I want to communicate back and forth between the two applications.**

**How can I do this?**

Server 1 has basically no logic besides basic Express boilerplate. On the Server 2 application I have this code to handle the POST req.:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.mensaje)
  res.send(req.body.mensaje)
})
```

The message gets logged to the console, and the res.send also works but all in one tab.

Comment: There are actually _two_ questions: (1) How to synchronize data between two servers. (2) How to update a web page when data on the server change. Do you really need two servers?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen What I wanted to do is learning how two independent applications interact. My project idea is to create something similar to the backend of Uber Eats. I'd have two clients: the user's phone, and the restaurant's internal platform. When the user asks for a hamburger (on Server 1), a message would appear on the restaurant's platform (Server 2). Then the restaurant would accept the order and a message of confirmation would be sent to the user (Server 1). That's basically it.

Comment: Best separate this into _two_ questions at StackOverflow. They might require the expertise of different groups of users.